# Call upon method from user input

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on a project and I have been asked to create a puzzle type game based on a 2d array. I have created the methods which all work fine, but I dont quite know how to make it so that the user can call upon the methods via user input whilst the program is running.

I'd prefer not to upload my code as this is quite a big class and I don't want other class members to find this and copy my code.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Well, you obtain the input from the user, which depends upon whether it is a GUI or a console application. Then you compare the input to some set of allowable actions. You call appropriate methods. There are *tons* of examples on this site on obtaining user input and processing it.

Comment: If you can't post the exact code, it would help to have a simplified example that illustrates the issue.

Comment: make methods which let each user enter a valid array location in a given chance, Scanner class would be useful ig.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html I did something similar and created a simple tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple menu loop like this:

```
// scanner created outside the loop because it will be used every iteration
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Please choose an option: ");
    // read some input and trim the trailing/ leading whitespaace
    String input = s.nextLine().trim();
    // check to see which move was called
    if (input.equals("foo")) {
        foo(); 
    }
    else if (input.equals("bar")) {
        bar(); 
    }
    // break out of the menu loop
    else if (input.equals("exit")) {
        break; 
    }
    // if none of the above options were called 
    // inform user of invalid input
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
// exit program
System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

Just add in options as you need them

Answer (score -1):

You can use GUI or console to give your command to your apllication for execution those methods.

offtop

> this is quite a **big** class

I think you should divide one big class to some smaller classes(less them 100 lines).